# Dynamic Types, Extending Natives and hasOwnProperty() in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I stumbled across a paragraph in a book which says,

> The ***hasOwnProperty()*** technique also requires the ***property name***
>   as a ***string*** and will check if an ***object*** has the ***property directly on
>   that instance*** (and ***thus is not just an inherited prototype property***).

Fine, no issues with above line.

A few lines later in the same chapter,

Since JavaScript is a dynamic language, we may find that modifying the prototypes of native objects is very useful, albeit a bit dangerous.

> A very important note of warning should be stated here. The practice
>   of extending the ***prototypes of native objects*** is both useful and
>   ***dangerous***. For example, it is commonly forbidden to extend the ***native
>   Object prototype*** (from which ***all other objects inherit***), useful as
>   that may sound, because doing so causes ***those properties/methods to be
>   seen in for-in loops that do not properly filter with
>   hasOwnProperty().***

What does he actually mean when he puts forward this line,

> ... causes ***those properties/methods to be
>   seen in for-in loops that do not properly filter with
>   ***hasOwnProperty()***...

because, at one point shown above, he says

> ***hasOwnProperty()***- will check if an ***object*** has the ***property
>   directly on  that instance***

How can they(***properties defined on the prototype***) be  not properly filter with
***hasOwnProperty()***?

Doesn't the 2 statements seem to be contradict?

For your illustration you may take this one,

```
String.prototype.getThirdChar = function() {
return this.charAt(2);
};
```

and then,

```
var c = "Example".getThirdChar(); // c set to "a"
```

Answer (score 1):

This example illustrates the problem:

```
// in some file far far away
Object.prototype.foo = function() {};

// in your own code
var obj = { bar: 'bar' };
for (var i in obj) {
  console.log(i);
}
```

The logger will show two properties: `bar` (expected) and `foo` (probably not, as the code modifying `Object.prototype` is usually hidden beyond any rational measure in some utility module). The reason? Here it goes:

> Objects created from built–in constructors like `Object`
>   have inherited non–enumerable properties from `Object.prototype`. The loop will iterate over all enumerable properties of the object itself and those the object inherits from its constructor's prototype (properties closer to
>   the object in the prototype chain override prototypes' properties).

So if you want to iterate over object's own properties, you just have to recheck the property's ownership:

```
for (var i in obj) if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
  console.log(i); // just 'bar', nothing weird to see here, move along
}
```

Note the difference with the following:

Comment: What is the author trying to suggest with, ...not properly filter with hasOwnProperty()...? Since as per my understanding, hasOwnProperty() will reveal only those properties present directly on the object.

Comment: With `for...in`, you expect to iterate over own properties of the object (without touching its prototype methods, like `.toString`, and `.valueOf` etc. The gotcha is that have anyone augmented `Object.prototype` with their own properties/methods, you'll get those listed in `for..in` too. That's why filtering is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Well there are values and prototypes.

```
o = {
    string: "is found by hasOwnProperty",
    fn: function(){}
}

Object.prototype.foo = function() {};

for(var prop in o){
    console.log(prop)
}

for(var prop in o){
    if(o.hasOwnProperty(prop){
        console.log(prop)
    }
}
```

First will result into "string,fn,foo"
Second in "string,fn"

However I usually use a lot of prototype extending. There is a way to extend prototype without messing with for in loops.

```
Object.defineProperty(Object,'boo',{
    value: function(arg){
        ...
    },
    enumerable: false // not findable in for-in
})

for(var prop in o){
    console.log(prop)
}
```

Object.defineProperty is the key https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty